How to capture spacebar key pressed in other Word document
I am using Microsoft Word VBA. I have two documents, A.doc and B.doc. I can put a macro in A.doc but not in normal.dot or B.doc. So B.doc cannot have any code.
What code could I put in A.doc, so that when the spacebar is typed while editing B.doc, a macro named Process_SpaceBar() in A.doc is called?
I tried Application.KeyBinding but it works only in the document in which code resides.

Apart from the brute force method of assigning a keyboard shortcut to a macro, which needs to be in the document or its attached template, there is no method in VBA to detect a key press.
